# Laravel 5.3 CLI stop working when using foreach on array request

Tags: php, laravel, command-line-interface, laravel-5.3

I have this form structure

```
<form> <!-- assume I have method and action attribute in the form -->
    <fieldset>
        <input type="checkbox" name="settings[]" value="1" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="settings[]" value="2" checked>
        <input type="checkbox" name="settings[]" value="3" checked>
    </fieldset>
    <button>Save</button>
</form>
```

and then tried to catch the array requests

```
//route
Route::post('/settings/save','SettingsController@save_settings');
//in controller
public function save_settings(Request $request){
    foreach($request->settings[] as $s){
        //save settings
    }
}
```

and every time I hit the form button, the Laravel CLI suddenly stop working.

[image]

If I remove the 'foreach', everything is normal like there's no 'CLI stop working'. Any ideas, help please? I'm using Laravel 5.3, php 7, wamp.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
public function save_settings(Request $request){
    $setting=Input::get('settings');
    $count=count($setting);
    if($count >0 ){
        foreach($setting as $s){
            //save settings
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: foreach($setting as $s){
            //save settings
        }

Comment: you can use this also

Answer (score -1):

Replace your controller function with this.

```
public function save_settings(Request $request)
{
  foreach($request->get('settings') as $s) {
    //save settings
  }
}
```

Please understand that to get any input from $request, use the `get()`/`all()`/`except()`/`only()`/`input()` function :)

Documentation is given [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input)

Comment: what? in my projects, I can just do $request->theinputvalue without any problems. Either in get or post, I can just do $request->theinputvalue.

Comment: @CodeDemon Did you try my answer?